# Link (to open source repository) does not work in the PDF if the URL contains a dash

Tags: bug, status-planned, developer-story

Example link: https://github.com/danielvarga/hunglish-webapp/commits

It appears OK in the PDF document (created by the 'Save as PDF' button on the developer story page), but it can't be clicked.

When I copy it, and paste it into a text editor, it looks like this:

```
https://github.com/danielvarga/hunglish%E2%80%90webapp/
```

I am not sure. This '‐' may be a different kind of dash, not the normal one. `%E2%80%90`

In the description box, the link works OK.

Comment: Generating a PDF from https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/176569 in Firefox Nightly 94.0a1 and clicking the link works fine.

Comment: So the dash is being escaped into the wrong one? Or is the original link wrong? The proper URL uses `- U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS`, while the escaped version is the incorrect `‐ U+2010 : HYPHEN`, which causes [a 404 on GitHub](https://github.com/danielvarga/hunglish%E2%80%90webapp/commits).